# Accessing dictionary within url tag (Django)

Tags: django

I have the following Jinja code for my Django application:

```
      <ul>
        {% for key, value in course_avrg.items %}
          <li>
            <a href="{% url 'course-detail' pk=course_ids[key] %}">{{ key }}:</a> {{ value }}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

The `course_ids` is a dictionary with key `course name` (str) and value `course id` (int).

The `course_avrg` is another dictionary with key `course name` (str) and value `course average` (int)

In the above code, I'm trying to get the primary key value (int) of each course by passing the course name `"key"` into `course_ids` dictionary.

However, I get the following error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '[key]' from 'course_ids[key]'

so how should I access dictionary value from within the Jinja URL tag?

Comment: This appears to be Django template language, not Jinja.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am using Jinja template designer. I used the following documentation: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/

Comment: You might be reading the Jinja documentation, but you are definitely using the Django template language. If you weren't, you would need to be using `items()` not just `items`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
@register.filter
def getvalue(dict, key):    
    return dict[key]
```

And use it in template like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'course-detail' pk=course_ids|getvalue:key %}">{{ key }}:</a> {{ value }}
```

Comment: I have tried that too, But I get the following error:

Reverse for 'course-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard\\/course\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Comment: @Amir lloks like you dont have some course names in `course_ids`.

Comment: I have doubled check that with python manage.py shell. I have all the values. course_ids is currently {'CPSC317': 2, 'MATH200': 3, 'PHYS341': 4}

Comment: course_avrg value is {'CPSC317': 96.73, 'MATH200': 77.94, 'PHYS341': 85.5}

Comment: neverwalkaloner   where should I add getvalue function? in my views.py? and how should I pass it to my template?

Comment: @Amir You should add this code inside `templatetags` directory. Check this doc for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters You may also try this tutorial:http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html

Comment: neverwalkaloner I will look at the tutorials tomorrow. It seems to be the solutions I'm looking for. I will let you know. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177129/discussion-between-amir-and-neverwalkaloner).